# Apache2 connection reset from HTML post form

Tags: python, connection, apache2, cgi, reset

/var/log/apache2/error.log shows the following:

> [Mon Nov 13 00:37:42.530977 2017] [cgid:error] [pid 24429:tid 140656362030848] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 127.0.0.1:37890] AH02550: Failed to flush CGI output to client, referer: http://www.site[dot]com/

The error occurs when initializing a simple Hello World cgi via HTML post form submission. Here is the HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>XLSX to TMX Converter</title>
</head>
<body>

<form name="uploadform" action="cgi-bin/upload.cgi" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div align="left">
<p>
<label for="srcdropdown"> Source language </label>
<select name="srcdropdown">
<option value="en">English</option>
<option value="de">German</option>
</select>
</div>
<div align="left">
<label for="tgrdropdown"> Target language </label>
<select name="tgrdropdown">
<option value="en">English</option>
<option value="de">German</option>
</select>
</p>
</div>


<br><br>
<input type="file" name="fileupload" value="fileupload" id="fileupload" multiple="multiple">
<label for="fileupload"> Select a file to upload</label>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf has not be altered. Here is

/etc/apache2/sites-available/site.com.conf is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@gmail.com
    ServerName site.com
    ServerAlias www.site.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site.com/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The python script is at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/upload.cgi and looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "HELLO WORLD"
```

The reset only occurs when I access the script via post submission. I get no error when I refresh the page with the script address in the browser, i.e. www.site.com/cgi-bin/upload.cgi

Comment: Additionally the reset is avoided when GET method is used instead of POST for the form, but this is not great for uploading large files.